# Mongo Connection Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cloud-foundry

I'm new to rails. I would like to push a simple rails application to cloudfoundry and I am getting an error:

```
 ====> /logs/stderr.log <====
/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/mytestapp-0
-4a068e3fd2b22422bdd29f3762e9bc9b/app/rubygems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongo-
1.6.4/lib/mongo/connection.rb:420:in `connect': Fail:27017  (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
```

The sample app gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

mongo.yml:

```
defaults: &defaults
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 27017

development:
<<: *defaults 
database: cloud_foundry_rails_tutorial_development

test:
<<: *defaults
database: cloud_foundry_rails_tutorial_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production: 
host: <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-2.0'].first['credentials']['hostname']  
rescue 'localhost' %>

port: <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-2.0'].first['credentials']['port']    
rescue '27017' %>

database: <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-2.0'].first['credentials']['db'] 
rescue 'cloud_foundry_rails_tutorial' %>

username: <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-2.0'].first['credentials']['username'] 
rescue '' %>

password: <%= JSON.parse( ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'] )['mongodb-2.0'].first['credentials']['password'] 
rescue '' %>
```

I was able to push to CF last week without any issue but now it doesn't work? Is there something that changed on the CF side?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFoundry.com upgraded from MongoDB 1.8 to 2.0 last week, and that's likely affecting your app. I will be checking with the CF.com engineering team and filing a bug if necessary.

However, since you're manually specifying connection information in `mongo.yml`, have you disabled auto-config of services? To do so, create the file `config/cloudfoundry.yml` and add:

```
autoconfig: false
```

For more information on auto-config of services in Ruby apps, see http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/03/12/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-ruby-part-1-auto-reconfiguration/

Comment: Thank you Glenn for your quick reply. I added autoconfig: false to the config/cloudfoundry.yml and I still get the same error message “Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure) “ Do I need to update the Gemfile?

Comment: I tried to duplicate your app at http://ghomongo.cloudfoundry.com. The source is at https://github.com/oppegard/rails-mongo-demo. Can you compare to your app?

Comment: Thank you so much @Glenn..It worked great like a charm;  I push it to CF without any problem. I compared it to my app, and I noticed that I don’t have database.yml in application. 
Creating the new apps with –skip-active-record is a must correct?

Comment: My app was created with `--skip-active-record` but still had a database.yml. CF engineering is investigating why the app won't work if the file doesn't exist (possibly a bug).